# How to use gccxml with incomplete dependency?

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, code-analysis

I am trying to calculate some code metrics of a set of C++ files. I find that available tools are either expensive or quite old, so I choose to

1. parse the files with gccxml
2. analyze the output xml-file.

Then I meet the problem that some of headers are not ready:

error: js-config.h: No such file or directory // but js-config.h.in is in the folder

error: jsautocfg.h: No such file or directory

Since what I want is the basic structure of each C++ file, is it possible to make gccxml output the xml-file anyway?

Comment: Did you investigate the various tools which come with clang <http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html>? That has the advantage of being actively maintained, with a large user community.

Comment: @rici Thank you for your advice! It seems that [LibTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) could meet my needs~.

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine the structure of C++ with such incomplete information:

```
#include "js-config.h"

void foo()
{
  bar();
}
```

What's bar()? It can be a macro, a type, a function, a functor. The problem is that you need such information because otherwise parsing can break down completely:

```
void foo()
{
  (int) x(bar & bar); // What the hell is this?
}
```

Comment: You are RIGHT..(I should've considered more carefully before asking...)  Thank you.!